# Any books similar to Hungerford's Abstract Algebra: An Introduction?

Tags: self-learning, education, book-recommendation

I'm an electrical engineer with the usual math background for engineering (mostly calculus, vector calculus, some DEs, Fourier, some complex analysis, linear algebra). Years ago I picked up a copy of Hungerford's Abstract Algebra: An Introduction (probably off of the streets of Cambridge MA when somebody cleaned out their apartment). I had absolutely no background in abstract algebra, but I've been able to teach myself from this book. It's slow going, but once in a while I'll pick it up and spend a few minutes reading before bed every night for a month before putting it back down. It's really interesting stuff and I've learned a ton.

My question: are there books on other topics (not abstract algebra) at a similar difficulty level? Something that a non-mathematician could use for self-learning? Most serious math books seem to jump right in with definitions and proofs. Hungerford motivates and explains a lot in plain English.

So...any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're asking a really broad question (not abstract algebra implies too many topic possibilities). I am not sure it belongs here. Maybe say at least which math topics would you like to study.

Comment: Also, questions like this (but more focused) have been asked and answered here before.  Click on the book-recommendation tag and you'll find over 2,500 questions with that tag. Or go to the MAA website, and look for their pages of book reviews.

Comment: Yep super vague I know. Most of the recommendation posts that I've seen are much more advanced. And honestly I'm up for studying anything. I'd never have thought that abstract algebra would be fun but it is. Should I just look, in general for 2nd/3rd year undergrad sort of books? I'll check out some of the other posts to see if they're helpful at all.

Comment: _Introduction to Graph Theory_ by Trudeau is a very gentle introduction to the subject of Graph Theory. It doesn't require anything beyond high school algebra. Since it is Dover publication, the book also has the advantage of being quite inexpensive.